# Не создается окно на WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

При работе с кодом все идет нормально. При сборке ошибок компилятора нет. Однако само окно не создается, хотя когда копирую код из интернета, вставляю и запускаю все нормально. Проблема может быть с инициализацией класса или с самим окном(CreateWindow). Вот код для просто создания окна:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE app, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR ipCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND window;
    MSG msg;
    TCHAR ClassName[] = L"MyClass";

    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);

    // Тоже проверка. Всё может тут и закончиться
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Ошибка: Не зарегистрировался класс!", L"Ошибка!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return NULL;
    }

    // Создание самого окна
    window = CreateWindow(
        ClassName,
        L"Тест",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        app,
        NULL
    );

    // Проверка. Именно тут все и заканчивается
    if (!window)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Ошибка: Не создалось окно!", L"Ошибка", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return NULL;
    }

    ShowWindow(window, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return NULL;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        break;

    default:
        DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

P.S.: Тут проблема с окном

Comment: Не помогает((. Ни при добавлении в switch, ни при обычном возврате функции, ни при обеих вариантах.

Comment: еще выставляйте окну нормальные координаты и габариты при создании, а то у вас  CW_USEDEFAULT x 0

Comment: Тип: проект я сделал через Мастер классических приложений Window(через .exe) + Пустой проект и доваил один файл .cpp.
nCmdShow я сделал SW_USEDEFAULT
`while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
{
 TranslateMessage(&msg);
 DispatchMessage(&msg);

 OutputDebugString((LPCTSTR)&msg);
}`
Надеюсь с OutputDebugString я правильно сделал(

Comment: @ЧелизОМОНа, Вам вообще-то сказали добавить ключевое слово `return` перед `DefWindowProc`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При работе с `WinAPI`, нужно проверять не только на валидность значений которые возвращают функции, но и вызывать `GetLastError`, что бы получить дополнительную информацию о том, что пошло не так, и почему функция вернула данные `NULL`.

Ниже, просто исправленный код...

P.S. Код на си, т.к. мне не вариант было переключать компилятор ради исправления ошибок.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE app, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR ipCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    (void)ipCmdLine;
    (void)hPrev;

    HWND window = NULL;
    MSG msg = {0};
    TCHAR ClassName[] = __TEXT("MyClass");
    DWORD error_code = 0UL;
    char error_buffer[1024] = {0};

    WNDCLASSEX wc = {0};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);

    // Тоже проверка. Всё может тут и закончиться
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        error_code = GetLastError();
        sprintf(error_buffer, "GetLastError(): Error Code %lu", error_code);
        OutputDebugStringA(error_buffer);
        MessageBox(NULL, __TEXT("Ошибка: Не зарегистрировался класс!"), __TEXT("Ошибка!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return 1;
    }

    // Создание самого окна
    window = CreateWindowA(
        ClassName,
        __TEXT("Test"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        app,
        NULL);

    // Проверка. Именно тут все и заканчивается
    if (!window)
    {
        sprintf(error_buffer, "GetLastError(): Error Code %lu", error_code);
        OutputDebugStringA(error_buffer);
        MessageBox(NULL, __TEXT("Ошибка: Не создалось окно!"), __TEXT("Ошибка"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

        return 2;
    }

    ShowWindow(window, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0LL;
}
```

```
ヒミコ@DESKTOP-T4M5L89 MINGW64 /d/some/build
$ make some
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/some.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable some.exe
[100%] Built target some

ヒミコ@DESKTOP-T4M5L89 MINGW64 /d/some/build
$ ./some.exe 

ヒミコ@DESKTOP-T4M5L89 MINGW64 /d/some/build
$ echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новый пустой проект(файл->создать->проект->Visual C++->Пустой проект), и вручную добавьте main.cpp и напиши заново код.